# Problems Modifying a Github Project to Include mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm having issues converting this setup: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Nodejs-Passport-Login

to push and pull user data from a mysql database.  I've got the registration to work just fine, but I appear to be having difficulty with the login portion.  I converted this portion from lines 14-18 of server.js

```
initializePassport(
  passport,
  email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
  id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)
```

to look like this

```
initializePassport(
  passport, 
  email => db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw (err)
    const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?"
    const searchQuery = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [email])
  
    await connection.query(searchQuery, async (err, result) => {
      connection.release()
      
      if (err) throw (err)
      console.log(result[0].email)
      return result[0].email
    })
  }),
  id => db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw (err)
    const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?"
    const searchQuery = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [id])
  
    await connection.query(searchQuery, async (err, result) => {
      connection.release()

      if (err) throw (err)
      console.log(result[0].id)
      return result[0].id
    })
  })
)
```

Basically, the initial setup found the relevant data from an array called "users", so I figured I could do the same with the mysql database.  I have not changed the passport-config.js file, as I figured it didn't need it, but now I'm not so sure.

During login, the terminal logs the correct input email on login as per my modifications, but it never gets to the id portion of this.  Also, it throws the programmed message "No user with that email" as found in line 8 of passport-config.js.

The rest of the code I have in my file is basically the same except for the database connection which looks like this (all the stuff references a .env file that has all the correct params):

```
const DB_HOST = process.env.DB_HOST
const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER
const DB_PASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASSWORD
const DB_DATABASE = process.env.DB_DATABASE
const DB_PORT = process.env.DB_PORT

const mysql = require("mysql")
const db = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: DB_HOST,
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASSWORD,
  database: DB_DATABASE,
  port: DB_PORT
})
```

and the registration post method which looks like this:

```
app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = Date.now().toString()
    const fName = req.body.firstName
    const lName = req.body.lastName
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)

    db.getConnection( async (err, connection) => {
      if (err) throw (err)
      const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fName = ?"
      const searchQuery = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [fName])
      const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
      const insertQuery = mysql.format(sqlInsert,[id, fName, lName, email, password])
      await connection.query (searchQuery, async (err, result) => {
       if (err) throw (err)
       console.log("------> Search Results")
       console.log(result.length)
       if (result.length != 0) {
        connection.release()
        console.log("------> User already exists")
       } 
       else {
        await connection.query (insertQuery, (err, result)=> {
        connection.release()
        if (err) throw (err)
        console.log ("--------> Created new User")
        console.log(result.insertId)
       })
      }
     }) //end of connection.query()
     }) //end of db.getConnection()
    res.redirect('/login')
  } catch {
  res.redirect('/register')
  }
})
```

As I said, I have no issues with the registration.  The connection is successful, and subsequent inspection of the users table in the mysql terminal (I'm using Mac), the data is being stored correctly.  How do I proceed here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the return in `initializePassport` function.

When you `return result[0].email` or `return result[0].id` it returns out of the inner callback function of `connection.query()` not the outer function.

This may fix it:

```js
initializePassport(
  passport,
  (email) =>
    db.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
      const searchQuery = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [email]);

      // return out of db.getConnection()
      return connection.query(searchQuery, async (err, result) => {
        connection.release();

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result[0].email);
        // return out of connection.query()
        return result[0].email;
      });
    }),
  (id) =>
    db.getConnection(async (err, connection) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
      const searchQuery = mysql.format(sqlSearch, [id]);

      // return out of db.getConnection()
      return connection.query(searchQuery, async (err, result) => {
        connection.release();

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result[0].id);
        // return out of connection.query()
        return result[0].id;
      });
    })
);
```

Comment: Gave it a shot and no dice...

Comment: I realised that this too won't work because the issue is you can't return from asynchronous callback call from an synchronous function.

Comment: Instead write your database queries and logic inside `authenticateUser` function.